# Facebook.notifications.send not working with FBJS

Tags: facebook, fbjs

I know the notification.send is about to be deprecated but I still wanted to try it out.  I'm using javascript on client side and want to send notifications from the client side. I'm using

```
Facebook.notifications.send('uid','message','user_to_user'
```

Doesn't return me any results also tried.

```
Facebook.notifications_send('uid','message','user_to_user')
```

Any Ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible to use FBJS with sending notification

in PHP use:
$facebook->api_client->notifications_send($uid, 'message', 'user_to_user');

Comment: apparently I did send notifications using the method :) Just lost it now.

Answer (score 0):

notifications_send is outdate method. you will receive an empty response. check on new ghrap sytem on 
http://developers.facebook.com/